# How to place arrays from a class into a single array located in another class?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a main program with a set of arrays that looks as shown below. These arrays are then imported to another class (second.java) . Here I wanted all the arrays to be placed into a single array('Complete_array') so that I could access each one of them individually at the end of the program.

```
     Main.java

  public class Main{

  public enum State{A,D,H};

  Test[] tests = new Test[]{
           new Test(new State[]{State.A, State.H, State.A, State.H}),
           new Test(new State[]{State.A, State.H, State.A, State.D}),
           new Test(new State[]{State.H, State.D, State.A, State.A})
   };
```

The second class looks like this:

```
  public class Test{

public static Main.State[] in;
public static Main.State[] in_state= new Main.State[4];
public static String data_in;

Test(Main.State[] in){
    this in = in;
    this.in_state=in_state;

for( int i=0; i<in.length; i++){
    in_state[i]=in[i];
    data_in =java.util.Arrays.toString(in_state);
    data_in = data_in.replaceAll(",", "");
    data_in = data_in.replaceAll(" ","");}
```

System.out.println( "The input arrays are" +data_in) ;

I get the outoput at the end as

```
The input arrays are[AHAH]
The input arrays are[AHAD]
The input arrays are[HDAA].
```

Instead of this I wanted to find a way to put these arrays into a single array. Something like this:

```
complete_array[] = [AHAH,AHAD,HDAA].
```

Could somebody please tell me how could I acheive this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question an hour ago? :)

Comment: @kocko: It wasnt the same question :) I had asked previously how could I concatenate these arrays into a single string. But then I realized it was not right. Thus I was looking now for a way to add these arrays into a single complete array :)

Comment: This code is wrong at so many levels. And is confusing. What is your goal here exactly?

Comment: @SamratDutta: this code is part of a bigger picture I am trying to create. From this code I just intend to access the arrays by placing them into a single array. Sorry if it sounds confusing. And may I know why is it wrong according to you?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to do here.. If you need to print a 2-D array, you can use `Arrays.deepToString()`. I also suggest you to give *proper* names to fields

Comment: @Goldengirl, syntax errors mainly. this.in = in, and then what does this.in_state = in_state even mean in this code? It does absolutely nothing. Its like saying int a = 4; a=a; Plus, if you want to print things in the second class, what is the purpose of calling new Test[] in the main.java class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your code is a little bit confusing. I still get your point. You want to combine two arrays into one, right?

This might help:

```
int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] array2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
//make a new array and put all the stuff of the two arrays in it.
int[] combined = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++) {
    combined[i] = array1[i];
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++) {
    combined[i + array1.length] = array2[i];
}
```

This isn't the best way to do it, I think. But it's still a solution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That Is exactly what I meant :) Thank you for this. I think this might work. But I still have one issue. As you see my arrays are part of the main program. So everytime I access one array from the main class via the second test class the previously stored array is over written by the incoming array. How could I avoid this overwritting? Could you please suggest something? :)

Comment: @Goldengirl I don't quite understand what your code does but I guess that if you want to prevent overwriting, You can just copy the array to another array. Just use the Arrays.copyOf method. You'll figure out how by reading the docs.

Comment: @Goldengirl The fields of the Test class should not be static.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a POJO class of single array which will hold the base address of all the different arrays and you can access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a **List** in your **Main** which will pack all your arrays of States like the following:

```
private  List<State[]> list_states = new ArrayList<State[]>(); 

list_states.add(new State[]{State.A, State.H, State.A, State.H});
list_states.add(new State[]{State.A, State.H, State.A, State.D});
list_states.add(new State[]{State.H, State.D, State.A, State.A});
```

After that you can send to your class **Test** this List like that:

```
new Test(list_states);
```

In case of the class Test, it would look like that:

```
public class Test{
public static Main.State[] in_state= new Main.State[4];
private List<State[]> list_states = new ArrayList<State[]>();


Test( List<State[]> in){
    this in = in;
    this.in_state=in_state;

for (State[] array: in){

    for( int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        in_state[i]=array[i];
        data_in =java.util.Arrays.toString(in_state);
        data_in = data_in.replaceAll(",", "");
        data_in = data_in.replaceAll(" ","");}
        this.in_state=in_state;
    }

}
```

I hope it will help you in some way :) (Code can be improved more with the idea that you want, bu this is a first draft)

Comment: But he wants an array, not a list.

Comment: @Sweeper It is truth :) I was out of mind xD, I will still keep the solution if someone wants to do it in other way, but your solution looks perfect with the requirements specified!